# How to change right-arrow icon to access hidden menu items in QMenuBar using PyQt5?

Tags: stylesheet, pyqt5, qmenubar

[image]

I found no references about this in the documentation.

Comment: Please provide some more information. What specifically do you want to change about it?

Comment: Color to #ccc is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot easily style this "extension" button because that symbol is actually an icon.

You can however access the `QToolButton` widget to set the icon to whatever you like. In PyQt4 you get to it with `menubar.children()[0]`. This should be consistent with PyQt5. Looking at the Qt5 [source code](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/20147fae60fd062788c51b058ebb70b33d7fd664/src/widgets/widgets/qmenubar.cpp#L687), it appears that the extension icon is always created first, even if it is not shown, and the `children()` method returns objects in the order in which they were created (this the index of 0).

Once you have a reference to the `QToolButton`, you can then set the icon to whatever you like with `menubar.children()[0].setIcon(my_qicon)` (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

*Since this is one of the top items on google for modifying the "show more" icon:*
Another option is to use a `QToolbar`. You can do the same thing except that the first child is a layout, second is the `QToolButton` that you want:

```
from qtpy import QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys

def call_back():
    print('pressed')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(widget)
toolbar = QtWidgets.QToolBar()
layout.addWIdget(toolbar)

# add some actions
for i in range(10):
    toolbar.addAction('test_{}'.format(i), call_back)

# change the icon, the first child is a layout!, the second it the toolbtn we want!
toolbar.children()[1].setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('path/to/image.png'))

widget.show()
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

[image]